# How to get a content script to click the LIKE button of a YouTube video?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm learning how to make Web Extensions and thought it would be fun to start by doing an extensions that likes a YouTube video.

My manifest portion to interact with YouTube is as follows:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "js": ["/content_scripts/youtube.js"]
    }
  ],
```

My code is as follows:

```
    let likeButton = document.querySelector('button[title="I like this"]');
    if (likeButton != null) {
        likeButton.click();
        console.log(likeButton);
        console.log("clicked on like button");
    }
```

In my console I can see the log "clicked on like button". I can also see the button itself, but the "click" part never goes thru, or at least it doesn't actually "like" the video.

If I inspect the loged "likeButton", I can see this:

```
<button class="yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-opacity yt-uix-button-has-icon no-icon-markup like-button-renderer-like-button like-button-renderer-like-button-unclicked  yt-uix-post-anchor yt-uix-tooltip" type="button" onclick=";return false;" title="I like this" aria-label="like this video along with 637 other people" data-post-action="/service_ajax" data-force-position="true" data-orientation="vertical" data-position="bottomright" data-post-data="se=8pH38AERCAASDQoLeHRRQ1FZbEdTem8%3D&amp;itct=CDQQpUEiEwi0iLq78sLTAhUHz5AKHQxkD1wo-B0" data-tooltip-text="I like this" aria-labelledby="yt-uix-tooltip166-arialabel">
```

If I put that in a variable in the Google Chrome's console, put it on a variable and "click" it with button.click();, it works. But the content script doesn't, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You could alternatively use the Youtube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
var likeButton = document.querySelector('#top-level-buttons > ytd-toggle-button-renderer:nth-child(1) > a > #button')
if (likeButton) {
  likeButton.click();
}
```